# How we can create a hyperlink in default.ctp, Am I create an other controller to redirect it or somthing else?

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink

So please help me in this issue, how to give hyperlink in cakephp and my rout file is as following:

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'home', 'display'));
Router::connect('View/pages/*', array('controller' => 'admin_login', 'action' =>'admin_login', 'home'));

my hyperlink is in  default.ctp is :

href=admin_login.php

Is there something different from this

Comment: Please elaborate your question. I can't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
echo $this->Html->link('Click', '/page/home');
```

if you want to use .html then add this line into routes.php

```
Router::parseExtensions('html');
```